# Why is 22 the only result for the eheight?

Tags: arrays, function, visual-c++

I use the function f to evaluate eheight using time as the input.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

float f(float x)
{
    return(22 - ((1 / 2) * 386.4 * pow(x, 2)));
}
int main()
{
    float time[9] = { 0.03,0.0633,0.0967,0.13,0.1633,0.1967,0.2300,0.2633,0.2967 };
    float height[9] = { 22,21.5,20.5,18.8,17,14.5,12.0,8,3 };
    float eheight[9];
    cout << "Time(s)\tHeight(in)\tExperimental height(s)"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; ++i)
    {
        eheight[i] = f(time[i]);
        cout << time[i]<<"\t"<<height[i]<<"\t\t"<<eheight[i]<< endl;
    }
    
}
```

I use the function f to evaluate eheight using time as the input.

Answer (score 0):

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

float f(float x)
{
    return(22 - 0.5 * 386.4 * pow(x, 2));
}
int main()
{
    float time[9] = { 0.03,0.0633,0.0967,0.13,0.1633,0.1967,0.2300,0.2633,0.2967 };
    float height[9] = { 22,21.5,20.5,18.8,17,14.5,12.0,8,3 };
    float eheight[9];
    cout << "Time(s)\tHeight(in)\tExperimental height(s)"<<endl;
    for (int i = 0; i <= 8; ++i)
    {
        eheight[i] = f(time[i]);
        cout << time[i]<<"\t"<<height[i]<<"\t\t"<<eheight[i]<< endl;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).